# How to select retrieved data in HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I request a Resource from the backend-server in my Angular application . The Resource is multiple Environments which includes multiple databases.

the environment looks like this:

```
export class Environment {
    id: string;
    environmentName: string;
    databases: Database[];
    links: string[];
}
```

and the database in the environment looks like this:

```
export class Database {
    id: string;
    connectionName: string;
    dbSourcetype: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    connectionUrl: string;
    connectionStatus: string;
    databaseEnvironment: {
        creationDate: string;
        environmentName: string
    }
    creationDate: string;
    links: string[];
}
```

Now i want to implement a Form where i have to add a `select` with all databases. The `option` has to show the database-name and to which environment it belongs

this is my `HTML`:

```
<select>
    <div *ngFor="let environment of environments">
        <option *ngFor="let database of environment.databases" 
                [value]="database.id">
            {{environment.environmentName}}.{{database.connectionName}}
        </option>
    </div>
</select>
```

but the option shows nothing. when i just want to show the databases without `select`, like

```
<div *ngFor="let environment of environments">
  <div *ngFor="let database of environment.databases">
    {{environment.environmentName}}.{{database.connectionName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

then it works fine.

So how do i select the retrieved databases?

Comment: maybe you should try to use `<optgroup *ngFor="let environment of environments" [label]="environment.environmentName">` instead of div's?

Comment: you are exactly right, my friend! damn soo easy...thank you very much *-*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to use `<optgroup>` instead of `<div>`. Thanks to Anton Lee the problem was solved!